# Find the value of $\sin(2\theta)$ when $\cot(\theta) + \tan(\theta) = 2.5 $

Tags: trigonometry

I have an homework question that goes like:

$\cot(\theta) + \tan(\theta) = 2.5 $ is valid on some angles $\theta$ at section $0 < \theta < \pi/2$.

Find the value of $\sin(2\theta)$. (There is no need to find the value of $\theta$ in order to get the answer).

(a) $0.4 \quad$ (b) $0.5 \quad$ (c) $0.6 \quad$ (d) $0.7 \quad$ (e) $0.8$

An explanation on how to get the correct answer will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that

$$\cot(\theta)+\tan(\theta)=\frac{2}{\sin(2\theta)}$$

Comment: How did you get the $sin(2\theta)$ on the denominator?

Comment: The double angle formula for the sine function is $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
     \cot \theta+\tan \theta
  &= \frac{\cos \theta}{\sin \theta}+\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} \\
  &= \frac{\cos^{2} \theta+\sin^{2} \theta}{\sin \theta \cos \theta} \\
  &= \frac{1}{\sin \theta \cos \theta} \\
  &= \frac{2}{\sin 2\theta}
\end{align*}